# Executing rgrep non-interactively

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to run the rgrep command from a small Emacs Lisp utility, but I'm getting an odd error. The command description is:

> rgrep is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> (rgrep REGEXP &optional FILES DIR CONFIRM)
>
> Recursively grep for REGEXP in FILES in directory tree rooted at DIR.
>   The search is limited to file names matching shell pattern FILES.
>   FILES may use abbreviations defined in `grep-files-aliases', e.g.
>   entering`ch' is equivalent to `*.[ch]'.
>
> With C-u prefix, you can edit the constructed shell command line
>   before it is executed. With two C-u prefixes, directly edit and run
>   `grep-find-command'.
>
> Collect output in a buffer.  While find runs asynchronously, you can
>   use C-x ` (M-x next-error), or RET in the grep output buffer, to go to
>   the lines where grep found matches.
>
> This command shares argument histories with M-x lgrep and M-x
>   grep-find.

I try to run:

```
(rgrep "something" "all" "~/projects/")
```

and I get

```
 *** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Obviously all the params are strings, so I cannot understand where is this nil coming from.

I'm running Emacs 23.3 on Debian Testing.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Works just fine for me.  Try running in Emacs w/out your .emacs (`emacs -q`).  Also, before you run it, add `(setq debug-on-error t)` to get a backtrace which will provide more info.

Comment: You've probably ran rgrep interactively before running that code and you're value for grep-find-template is not nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think it's because you have no 'grep-find-template' defined. this is certainly (having debugged) why the command produces the error on my version. look at the help for that variable.

cheers.

ps. it's the difference between calling it interactively or not..

```
"find . <X> -type f <F> -print0 | \"xargs\" -0 -e grep <C> -nH -e <R>"
```

..gets set by 'grep-calc-defaults' when called interactively

pps. i think you just have to be careful with your call. if no matches are found, you'll get a 'Grep exited abnormally with code 123' error.

```
mkdir -p ~/a/b
cp ~/.bash* ~/a/b
emacs -q

C-x b <RET> *scratch*
(grep-compute-defaults)
(rgrep "^.*\\?\=.*$" "*bash*" "~/a")
```

..lots of matches!

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I don't understand something, however - if I call the calc-defaults directly before rgrep I get some abnormal exit error from find. It seems to me that the value of grep-find-template is looking good at the that point. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Bozhidar Batsov: Your usage of the `"all"` alias may also be an issue. That looks to be handled in the `interactive` call as well. You may wish to change that to the associated regexp `".*"`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get this when you call `rgrep` programmatically is that all the `interactive` calls to the variants of `grep` have a call to `grep-compute-defaults` in the `interactive` call.  This does not get evaluated when you're calling programmatically.

The easiest way to fix this is to add

```
(eval-after-load "grep"
  '(grep-compute-defaults))
```

in your code, which will force that to be called (but only when needed).

Comment: Yeah, I already figured that out. My real problem is that calling grep-compute-defaults before rgrep introduces some other problem - now I get an abnormal exit error from the find command that rgrep executes. Maybe there is something more that needs to be done other than invoking grep-computre-defaults?

Answer (score 2):

The following appears to work ok for me:

```
(defadvice rgrep (around rgrep-init)
  "Init grep defaults before calling rgrep non-interactively."
  (when (not (called-interactively-p))
    (grep-compute-defaults))
  ad-do-it)

(ad-activate 'rgrep)

(rgrep "something" "all" "~/projects/")
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Emacs manual:

> The commands M-x lgrep (local grep) and M-x rgrep (recursive grep) are more user-friendly versions of grep and grep-find, which prompt separately for the regular expression to match, the files to search, and the base directory for the search.

For the problem at hand, we don't need this 'user-friendliness' which gets in the way. We can use the plain "grep" elisp function which is better suited for non-interactive use. Basically this function takes as argument whatever grep command line you'd have to use to achieve the desired result. Maximum flexibility!

Here's what it would look like for your scenario:

```
(grep "grep --color -rn something ~/projects/")
```

Here's another, more complex use of grep's options, to match only complete words in Python files:

```
(grep "grep --include=\"*.py\" --color -rnw your_pattern files_root_dir")
```